# Can I determine which socket is closed when SIGPIPE risen?

Tags: macos, sockets, unix, networking, signals

I am working on a Mac OS application and using BSD Socket. I have several TCP sockets during run-time.

When SIGPIPE comes, what I know is that one or some socket(s) is/are closed by remote server. Is it possible to determine which socket(s) goes/go wrong when I catch the SIGPIPE signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is single threaded it is the last file descriptor that you wrote to. If multithreaded then you are out of luck.

I recommend that in both cases you just set SIGPIPE to SIGIGN and use the return value of write to determine a closed file descriptor.

Comment: Sadly, I may have socket amount up to 36 at one time and they are multi-threaded. As SIGPIPE is risen when trying to write to a closed socket, as you mentioned, will it risen again when I write to it just to check if it was closed? Meanwhile there may be one potential risks: If several sockets down at the same time, more write-to-check causes more SIGPIPE?

Comment: BTW I register the signal handler for SIGPIPE in my app and raise a global notification so that all threads may know without terminating the application.